# Value initialization vs aggregate initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++-2013

I am facing an issue with value initialization mixed with aggregate initialization.
So far, I tried to rely on doing all my initializations like this:

```
auto var = Type{};
```

(Yes, I am aware of brace-initializer ctor vs default ctor pitfall. So no comments about that please!)

I expect that this would properly "zero out" or init the memory of var.

But in VS 2013 Update 2, I see this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


struct B
{
    double g[10];
    std::string str;
};

struct C
{
    double g[10];
};

struct A
{
    double a[3];
    double b = 0;
    double d;
    struct B b_stuff;
    struct C c_stuff;
    A() : b_stuff{}, c_stuff{} {}
};

int main()
{
    auto a = A{};
    double big[50] = {};

    for(auto b : a.b_stuff.g) { cout << b << " "; }
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    for(auto b : a.c_stuff.g) { cout << b << " "; }
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    for (auto b : big) {  cout << b << " "; }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is this:

```
-9.25596e+061 -9.25596e+061 -9.25596e+061 -9.25596e+061 -9.25596e+061 -9.25596e+061 -9.25596e+061 -9.25596e+061 -9.25596e+061 -9.25596e+061

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

With GCC 4.7.2:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I read this but I don't see reason for this non-zeroing behaviour:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization

So, is VS 2013 buggy? Why doesn't it zero out the a.b_stuff.g array?

Comment: You are right, is a MSVC bug. You are correctly value initializing `b_stuff` (I have missed that line when writting my answer).

Comment: Huh, "good". I started to panic/hope that I missed something obvious. If this is really a bug in MSVC then that is bad news...

Comment: Try to use in-class value initialization, its allowed since C++11, but I don't know if the Microsoft folks implemented it: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e1e6d42289ce54ee

Answer (score 2):

Visual C++ has [a long and storied history of value initialization bugs](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/SearchResults.aspx?SearchQuery=C%2526%252343%253B%2526%252343%253B%2520%2526quot%253Bvalue%2520initialization%2526quot%253B). I believe [Bug 746973](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/746973/incorrect-c-11-value-initialization-for-type-with-implicitly-declared-but-non-trivial-default-constructor) is the one you have stumbled across here.

Comment: +1 [Yet another very old VC++ value-initialization bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/484295/)